# How to extract information from tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using the TortoiseSVN in a Delphi XE2 project.

I would like to extract the messages typed in the moment that I do the commit in the files to create a version documents for my clients. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN => Show Log

Then select the a range of revisions (click on the first or last revision you want included, then hold down shift, and click on the last revision).

Right-click on the highlighted revisions and select "Copy to Clipboard"

That will give you the log message + the modifications, in a fairly nicely formatted plaintext manner, and you can take that and format as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN supports client side hook scripts, so you can easily get the commit message.

This might be helpful: [Client Side Hook Scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)